# What will make google maps api clusters not work correctly?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am looking for help to understand why my customized google maps api map will not work with marker clusters. Below is the section of code I am using to coordinate markers on the map but I cannot get them to cluster.

With this map there is a marker that shows the user where they are and there are multiple markers with the setup as restaurant below (ex: theaters, shops, etc) to show users things around them and I am looking to get the restaurants to cluster together as well as other points that are similar but the clustering will not group.

```
<script>
if(output.restaurantmsg == "ok") {

 var image = {
url: 'img/Mobs/FK.png',
// This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
size: new google.maps.Size(35, 32),
// The origin for this image is (0, 0).
origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
// The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
};

var shape = {
coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
type: 'poly'
};

var restaurantslist = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < restaurantmaplistname.length; i++) {
restaurantslist[i] = new Array();
restaurantslist[i][0] = restaurantmaplistname[i];
restaurantslist[i][1] = parseFloat(restaurantmaplistlat[i]);
restaurantslist[i][2] = parseFloat(restaurantmaplistlng[i]);
restaurantslist[i][3] = i+1;
restaurantslist[i][4] = restaurantmaplistcontent[i];
}
//alert(dealslist);

  for (var i = 0; i < restaurantslist.length; i++) {
var restaurantli = restaurantslist[i];

//alert(dealli[1]+'-'+dealli[2]+'-'+(typeof dealli[1])+'-'+typeof dealli[2]);
var markers = locations.map(function(lat: restaurantli[1], lng: restaurantli[2], ) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat: restaurantli[1], lng: restaurantli[2]},
  map: map,
  icon: image,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  shape: shape,
  title: restaurantli[0],
  zIndex: restaurantli[3]
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var content = restaurantli[4];

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
    return function() {
       infowindow.setContent(content);
       infowindow.open(map,marker);
    };
})(marker,content,infowindow));
                            return marker;
                            });

}
                        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
                                                               imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
                                                               });

}
                       var locations = [{
                                        lat: restaurantli[1],
                                        lng: restaurantli[2],
                                        info: "marker 1"
                                        }, ];
                       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
</script>
```

Comment: are you seeing any errors in your browser console? because that javascript is invalid for many reasons (it won't even parse as valid javascript, so no wonder it doesn't do anything)

Comment: @JaromandaX I am unaware of any errors. The map just does not load. Where have I gone wrong to make it not do anything?

Comment: look in the browser developer tools console, and you will see that your code (that you posted) is not valid, therefore, it doesn't run at all, therefore you don't see a map

Comment: @JaromandaX If I remove the marker cluster related lines the map works just fine. I cannot get the marker clusters working. I added the tag to the code in the question.

Comment: adding the `<script>` tags does not make invalid code valid ... your code is invalid, a browser will fail to parse it, therefore nothing of it will run - your browsers developer tools console must have an error in it, or else you're posting code that is not the code you are having an issue with ... e.g. `var markers = locations.map(function(lat: restaurantli[1], lng: restaurantli[2], ) {...` completely wrong

Comment: the error in the browser could be `SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters`

Comment: also `var markers = locations.map(...` is executing **before** locations is declared - variable declarations are hoisted, not the assignments though

Comment: @JaromandaX if     var markers = locations.map(function(lat: restaurantli[1], lng: restaurantli[2], ) is wrong what should be there? The google maps api marker clustering reference guide list location, so I put the Lat and png of my marker points.

Comment: try some *valid code* instead - I have no idea what you meant to write - can you see that isn't valid syntax?